# How to make a Random Layout when button clicked

Tags: java, android, android-layout, random

Actually i want to make it Random class but then i think to much activity can make the app slow so i just want to make Relative layout Random

so i have 5 layout in one activity class

```
layout1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
layout2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);
layout3 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout3);
layout4 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout4);  
layout5 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout5);
```

and in each layout there is the button in there to make layout random again

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v){ 

        //The code to how make layout random

        }
     });
 }
```

and then how to make layout that already opened not open again if the button random was pressed? then if all layout was already opened it will open new activity class

can anyone help me explain with give some example code of that?

Comment: How do you do to open a new `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: take a look of my skeleton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially set visibility gone to all relative layouts and put all of them into View's ArrayList.

Get random number from 0 to List size.

Get View at random position and set its visibility to Visible and remove from ArrayList.

Do same thing until ArrayList is empty.

Create new activity when ArrayList is empty.

Code:

```
ArrayList<View> viewList=new ArrayList<>();
initLayouts(){
    layout1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    layout2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);
    layout3 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout3);
    layout4 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout4);
    layout5 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout5);


    viewList.add(layout1);
    viewList.add(layout2);
    viewList.add(layout3);
    viewList.add(layout4);
    viewList.add(layout5);

    for(int i=0;i<viewList.size();i++){
        viewList.get(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v){
        loadRandomLayout();
    }
});
}
public loadRandomLayout(){
    if(viewList.size()>0) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int number = r.nextInt(viewList.size());
        viewList.get(number).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewList.remove(number);
    }else{
        startActivity(new Intent(this,NewActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: it still error bro,  '<>' operator is not allowed for source level  below 1.7

Comment: Replace <View> with <>.

Comment: it still error if i replace the <view>, but if i delete <> it is done

Answer (score 3):

You could create random int as follows:

```
//To get a Random number 1-5 (I saw your RelativeLayouts and you've 5
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((5 - 1) + 1) + 1;
```

And then you could create a method to choose what to show :

```
public void ShowRelativeLayout(int rand){

 switch(rand){
  case 1:
    if (layout1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
     //Do nothing cause it's visible
     break;
 } else {
     layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     break;

 }
 case 2:
 ..........

}
```

Comment: but the layout that visible before is opened again

Comment: No, because you ask if the layout that has a random num is visibile don't do nothing, isn't what you want?

Answer (score 3):

Make an array to store the layout indexes.

```
RelativeLayout[] layout = new RelativeLayout[5];
layout[0] = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout[0]); // 0
layout[1] = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout[1]); // 1
layout[2] = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout[2]); // 2
layout[3] = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout[3]); // 3
layout[4] = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout[4]); // 4
```

Make a simple random number generator.

```
public void FindNewLayout ()
{

  Random r_generator = new Random();

  int randomNum;

  //now the only way to know which layouts have been shown before, you 
  //need to store the indexes that have been used before, somewhere. 
  //I recommend using an array.

  // count, and the array below should be initialized somewhere else 
  //rather than inside the method so that only one instance of each is 
  //created, but for simplicity I'll just put their initialization here
  int static count = 0; 
  //I'll explain below what count does.

  // the log array that remembers each layout change
  boolean[] log = new boolean[5];

  do 
  {
    //select new random number
    randomNum = r_generator.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    //in this case max = 4, min = 0, so replace these values in the 
    //equation above

    // check the log to see if the number has appeared again
    if ( log[randomNum] == false )
    {
      //Great! it hasn't appeared before, so change layout
      log[randomNum] = true;
      layout[randomNum].setVisibility = true;
      count++; // increases step
      break; //stops while because an unused layout has been found
    }

  }while (count<5)
  //if the value of count is equal to 5 then every layout has been used 
  //before so the do-while code should not be run again

}// end method
```

And the above method should be called whenever you want to try to change layout.

Finally, you can use something like the `Debugger.log("message");` statement 
to be printed on the console for debugging purposes if you want, in order to find out when the layout has changed.